# when click update button unzip the zip file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to unzip my zip file after clicking update button but it's not working properly any idea?

```
function check_values($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before)
{


    if ( !function_exists( 'unzip_file' ) ) 
    { 
     require_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php'; 
    } 

       $file = '/wp-content/themes/xyz/XML.zip';  
       $to = '/wp-content/themes/xyz/'; 

       $result = unzip_file($file, $to);        

      }

 add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 ); //don't forget the last argument to allow all three arguments of the function
```

Comment: Describe "is not working properly", please.

Comment: function execute ok but i can't find any out put. Out put mean unzip folder

Answer (score 0):

You need a full path for your file and your destination. Depending on what you are building there are built-in functions to get the path you need. Here is a link that lists them all:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

For testing purposes, you can try using ABSPATH.

```
$file = ABSPATH . '/wp-content/themes/xyz/XML.zip';  
$to = ABSPATH . '/wp-content/themes/xyz/';
```

Remember that WordPress allows it's users to change the location of its themes folder so using the correct function is better than hardcoding a path. My best guess without more information is that you should be using `get_stylesheet_directory();`.

If you don't have debugging turned on do so then recreate the issue:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Check your folder permissions:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Retry to unzip your file. Do any errors display?

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay. I did the changes according to your guide. But i can't see any extract file in the theme folder any idea ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your replayagain. Finally i fixed the issue

Comment: So glad you were able to fix the issue. Can you post what finally fixed the issue?